# What does こと mean in 彼らは騒々しいことおびただしい?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

Example sentence from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/8842/m0u/%E5%A4%A5%E3%81%97%E3%81%84/):

> 彼{かれ}らは騒々{そうぞう}しいことおびただしい They are making a terrible noise [racket].

I don't know if that's 事 or 言, or 殊 (or something else?) so no idea where to even start looking...

Comment: It might help if you provide more context. A lone sentence can be quite hard to decipher.

Comment: This is an example sentence from a dictionary. I am not looking for sentence meaning (there is a translation provided) but rather the usage of こと here and the grammar behind it.

Comment: We don't use much おびただしい besides "large in number" these days. Instead, we say ～ことはなはだしい for the same meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「[連体形]{れんたいけい} of Verb or Adjective + **こと** + adjective expressing an extreme degree」

is a fairly common set phrase used to describe an unusually large number or high frequency.  It is used most often when the speaker has a ***negative*** opinion of the fact being described.

「連体形」 means the attributive form.  「こと」 nominalizes the preceding verb or adjective ***and***, at the same time, emphasizes its meaning.

こと = 事, but hiragana is preferred for this usage these days.

Answer (score -2):

I'm fairly sure it's a nominalizer converting the adjective 騒々しい into a noun. In English it would mean "thing" with 騒々しいこと meaning the "noisy thing."

It's not usually written as a kanji, but 事 is the one to pick.

Comment: Why doesn't some form of postposition （が、は、など、 さえ　etc　etc) follow this noun? Is it colloquial usage where it's skipped?

Comment: It is not skipped.  It just is not there in the first place.

Comment: 「騒々しいこと」 does not mean "noisy thing" in this phrase.

Comment: 騒々しいこと is "(their act/state of) being noisy," not 騒々しいもの (="noisy thing").

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I didn't realize this point before.